# Google sites are not working with HTML input type"date" or "number"

Tags: html, forms, google-sites

I am making a form on a google site but that has to contain a "request date" and a "phone number" but google site is not accepting the type="number" and type="date" as an input. if i put the type="text" for both of the fields then the user will be able to enter any form of words.

Any suggestions in regards to google sites???

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation in Google Sites. It does not support the new HTML5 `input` types; if you try enter them in the code mode (`<HTML>`), they are removed. Consider using a different service for creating web sites.

P.S. You should not use `<input type="number">` but `<input type="tel">` for phone numbers, since phone numbers are not really numbers but strings of digits and possibly other characters. But Google Sites does not suppport `<input type="tel">` either.